# How can I insert a pdf into a resulting pdf in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I'm generating a pdf using iTextSharp using C#. I need to insert another pdf (except an image) to a certain position in a resulting pdf. How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: *"I need to insert another pdf (except an image) to a certain position in a resulting pdf"* - how exactly do you mean that? What shall happen to the image area? Shall it be covered with some colored rectangle? And how is that position characterized?